# QtConcurrent::map and list of pointers

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I've found a few references online where people state that this doesn't work, but they  never give an explanation of *why* this shouldn't work.

In pseudo-code I'm doing something like this:

```
void MyObject::doWork() {
    QList<Item *> worklist;
    for ( int i = 0; i < nitems; i++ ) {
       Item *item = getItem(i);
       if (item->isVisible()) {
          worklist.prepend(item);
       } else {
          worklist.append(item);
       }
    }
    QtConcurrent::map(worklist, procfunc);
}
```

In essence, create a list of objects to do work on, and put the more important objects at the front of the list. Then cause each item to process, hopefully taking advantage of how-ever-many cores are in the system.

I can print the contents of `worklist`, and it contains a bunch of reasonable-looking pointers. I can iterate over the list invoking `QtConcurrent::run` explicitly on each item, and that works fine.

With the `QtCuncurrent::map` interface, `procfunc` doesn't get the pointers, it gets some random-looking data. I've tried two different declarations of `procfunc` (with no warnings, which tells you something about the type-safety of this interface):

```
   static void profunc(Item *);
   static void profunc(Item *&); // Probably correct given the API definition
```

All the examples create a list of Objects, not pointers-to-Objects. The objects often implement Qt's "copy-on-write" semantics, but that doesn't really make a lot of sense in my application.

Is this possible? If so, what am I doing wrong? If not, can someone explain what is happening that makes this not possible?

Comment: Can you complete your example by making a *full* testcase?

Comment: what is the lifetime of the `worlist` variable?

Comment: The `worklist` variable was local scope and disappeared right after the call to `QtConcurrent::map`. I think that was part of the problem... see my answer below. I fundamentally misunderstood that `QtConcurrent::map` was modifying the sequence in-place, as opposed to the objects in the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says it, if you read carefully enough. There are two similar interfaces, QtConcurrent::map and QtConcurrent::mapped:

> QtConcurrent::mapped() takes an input sequence and a map function.
>   This map function is then called for each item in the sequence, and a
>   new sequence containing the return values from the map function is
>   returned.

...

> If you want to modify a sequence in-place, use QtConcurrent::map().

The key-phrase here is that this modifies the ***sequence***.

My initial read was the "map" modified the objects in place, and "mapped" made new copies of the objects... but in fact it is the sequence, not the objects, that differs in these interfaces. In my code the sequence dropped out of scope, as I assumed it was dealt with internally to QtConcurrent, but since I was using the interface that was supposed to modify the sequence in-place that couldn't have been true. Hence all the bogus data.

Which means this is the wrong API for the job I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If Item has a member function `void Item::procMyself()`
then wrap it as `void procfunc(Item*& item) { item->procMyself();}` and use it  `QtConcurrent::map(worklist, procfunc);`

If you only have a `void procThat(Item* item)`, wrap it as `void procfunc(Item*& item) { procThat(item);}`